# Issues linking functions despite being reported in dumpbin.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, pdf

I'm having serious issues linking a library despite doing the same routine I've done with all other libraries.  The library is libmupdf.lib (a pdf viewing library).

Anyways, I have compiled the .lib and added it as a "Additional Dependencies" in the linker, added the header includes as additional includes, and specified where VSC++ should look for the libraries.  It doesn't complain about not finding libmupdf.lib as linking begins.

I then get the standard looking linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl fz_strlcat(char *,char const *,int)" (?fz_strlcat@@YAHPADPBDH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl winerror(struct pdfapp_s *,int)" (?winerror@@YAXPAUpdfapp_s@@H@Z)
```

However, if I do the below I see that fz_strlcat is indeed in libmupdf.lib but prepended with a _ .... is this normal?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>dumpbin /SYMBOLS "libmupdf.lib" | "grep.exe" fz_strlcat
033 00000000 SECTC  notype ()    External     | _fz_strlcat
060 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _fz_strlcat
381 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _fz_strlcat
```

Note: I tried changing the call to fz_strlcat to _fz_strlcat and made the change in the header, but still no linkage.

Any clues or help is appreciated at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing the Fitz library.  This is part of the MuPDF project but it builds as a separate LIB file.

**Edit**
I stand corrected: in looking at the vcproj files on MuPDF's GIT repository, it appears that libmupdf.lib builds as one big library, with all the Fitz stuff as well as even 3rd party libraries per-se.

Now... in looking in more detail at the error message,  **this looks like a C vs C++ linkage issue**.  Am I wrong in seeing that the fz_strlcat function is called from C++, whereby fitz.h has maybe not been included with the `extern "C" {}` linkage?
What happen in such case is that C++ produces a mangled name for linkage (`fz_strlcat@@YAHPADPBDH@Z`), one that includes codes for the full signature of the function (parameter types etc.).
By adding

```
extern "C" {
   #include "fitz.h"   //  or whatever other include file which in turn includes fitz.h
}
```

around the includes that pertain to functions and variables in the libmupdf library, the LNK error should disappear.

Comment: The only libs I seem to be able to build from source are libmupdf.lib and libthirdparty.lib.  I can't see any library particular to fitz.  I can also build mupdf.exe (included in the source) with just libmupdf and librthirdparty - so far as I can see.

Comment: Your right, it's being called from C++ so I wrapped the includes. extern "C" {
#include <fitz.h>
#include <mupdf.h>
#include "pdfapp.h"
}  but the error changes to -> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fz_strlcat referenced in function _winerror

Comment: I read 32.6 on the C++ FAQ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html ... wrapping the includes should be enough? I shouldn't have to prepend all the prototypes in the header with extern "C" should I?

Comment: @jparanich: No, you do not need to do that; it is preferable to let the open source files as-is so that you can continue easily "evolving" with the repository when they come up with fixes etc.  The only reason to do so would to avoid adding the linkage directives at the level of [your] C++ source files.

Comment: @jparanich: it appears you used some of the "apps" code from the MuPDF source; that is where winerror is defined and referenced etc.  Apparently the code in there doesn't use the extern "C" linkage, and you may want to add it there.  In other words the problem isn't with libmupdf.lib per se but with the apps snippets/files that you used to make the library do stuff for your own application.

Comment: Okay, ignore my 2nd last message.. somewhere I removed the library from the dependencies.  I now have it linking strlcat but complains about all the standard C function being redefined so I changed the project settings to /NODEFAULTLIB; however, go figure, now libthirdparty.lib can't resolve external symbols.  Is it better to just try and compile libthirdparty and libmupdf with C++ rather than C? Thx for all your help.

Comment: And you're right, I am trying to implement pieces of the sample app code.

Comment: Alright, finally got it working and embedding pdfs in my program.  In the project properties I added the rule "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" with libcmtd.lib.  Seems to have worked! Thanks mjv

Comment: @jparanich: In retrospect I helped more by being some kind of a sounding board rather than effectively pointing you in the right direction. It was hard to see exactly what is going on and to complicate things further I only inspected the project files as plain text rather than loading them into VS.  I'm glad you're now up and running.  Cheers!